# My Route are Returning a 404, How can I Fix Them?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I defined my routes in a routes\web file.

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('impersonate/{$user_id}', 'HomeController@impersonate')->name('impersonate');
Route::get('impersonate_leave', 'HomeController@impersonate_leave')->name('impersonate_leave');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

HomeController Method :

```
public function impersonate($user_id){
        echo $user_id; die;
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        Auth::user()->impersonate($user);
        return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

But Its Returning Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: Can you upload full routes ?

Comment: @Md.SukelAli Yes I uploaded. You Can see in main question

Comment: here define https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters    just define Route::get('impersonate/{user_id}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess just because of the way you gave parameter in route(web.php).
You don't need to add a `$` sign to the parameter. simply right like below.

```
Route::get('impersonate/{user_id}', 'HomeController@impersonate')->name('impersonate');
```

Add get it from controller like the same way uh getting.

```
public function impersonate($user_id){
        echo $user_id; die;
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        Auth::user()->impersonate($user);
        return redirect()->route('home');
}
```